# Creating custom Django CharField with choices

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in the `models.py` file:

```
SENT = 0
ACEPTED = 1
DECLINED = 2

SHARE_STATUSES = (
  (SENT, 'Sent'),
  (ACCEPTED, 'Approved'),
  (DECLINED, 'Declined')
)

status = models.ResultStatusField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=SENT)
```

I would like to create a custom Django field type with the choices (that can be reuses throughout application modules, instead of copy-pasting it multiple times in different places).

I have read Django [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-model-fields/) on how to create custom fields, but didn't understand how to provide the choices.

```
class ResultStatusField(models.CharField):
  def __init__(self):
    SENT = 0
    ACCEPTED = 1
    DECLINED = 2

    SHARE_STATUSES = (
      (SENT, 'Sent'),
      (ACCEPTED, 'Approved'),
      (DECLINED, 'Declined')
    )
```

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `choices` to the keyword arguments:

```
class ResultStatusField(models.CharField):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    SENT = 0
    ACCEPTED = 1
    DECLINED = 2

    SHARE_STATUSES = (
      (SENT, 'Sent'),
      (ACCEPTED, 'Approved'),
      (DECLINED, 'Declined')
    )

    kwargs['choices'] = SHARE_STATUSES
    kwargs['default'] = SENT
    kwargs['max_length'] = 2

    super(ResultStatusField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: A question: tell me please, how can I set SENT as the default value for choices? And is it possible to set max_length to 2?

Comment: Sure it is possible. You can set any keyword argument to any desired value.  See the updated answer.